# Create multiple dynamic select filters based on an array with unique values to filter another array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently new to Vue.js and this is my first question on stack so forgive me if I am not the most clear.

I am trying to create multiple dynamic select filters to filter a list that I have gotten from an api using axios.

I have surfaced the data within my HTML template and have managed to create the two filters, my main issue is that I need the filters to only display unique values (no duplicates) and this is where I am struggling.

This is mainly a proof of concept for work which displays a group of users names, there label and position.  We where using angularjs before and are now looking to move over to Vue.js, so I haven't gotten to grips with it yet, and currently stumped as I don't understand how to make the information from one source data array filter another source data array.

Here is what I have currently in my app.js

```
new Vue({
        el: "#vueApp",        
        data: {
            users: [],
            JobRole: '',
            Label: '',
            search: '',
            JobRoles: [],
        },
        created: function() {
            this.getResults();
        },


        methods: {
            getResults: function() {
                var vm = this;
                axios.get("APIData").then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data.value);
                    vm.users = response.data.value;
                })
            },

            filterPosition:function() {
                var vm = this;
                vm.item.Position = event.target.value;
            },

            filterLabel:function() {
                var vm = this;
                vm.item.Meta.Label = event.target.value;
            }

        },

        computed: {

            JobRoleList: function(){
                var vm = this;
                var JobRoles = [];
                vm.users.forEach(function(item){
                    if(!JobRoles.includes(item.Position)){
                        JobRoles.push(item.Position);  
                        console.log(JobRoles);                          
                    }

                });

                return JobRoles;

            },

                filterAll: function(){
                    var vm = this;
                    var filtered = vm.users;
                    // var JobRoles = vm.JobRoles;

                    if (vm.search) {
                        filtered = vm.users.filter(function(item){
                            return item.People.Title.indexOf(vm.search) > -1
                        });
                    }

                    if (vm.Label) {
                        filtered = filtered.filter(function(item){
                            return item.Meta.Label.match(vm.Label)
                        });
                    }

                    if (vm.JobRole) {
                        vm.JobRole = filtered.filter(function(item){
                            return item.Position.match(vm.JobRole)
                            console.log(JobRole);
                        });
                    }

                    return filtered
                    console.log(filtered);
                },

}




});
```

Here is my Markup

```
<div id="vueApp">
    <div>
        <select v-model="JobRole">
            <option value="">Select a Position</option>
            <option v-for="item in JobRoleList" :value="item.Position">{{item}}</option>
        </select>

        <select v-model="Label">
            <option value="">Select a Label</option>
            <option v-for="item in filterAll" :value="item.Meta.Label">{{item.Meta.Label}}</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search...">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <!-- <th>People Title</th> -->
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="item in filterAll">
                <td>{{item.People.Title}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Meta.Label}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Position}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what I want to get to is have each filter to have unique values with no duplication and to filter the information within the list.

I have managed to create a unique value array for one of the select filters under JobRoleList, I just need to know how to have it communicate with the filterAll array, if I can get to that stage then all I would need to do is replicate that for the other filter.

I would appreciate any help and would be more than happy to provide more detail.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of your data? Also, it's not quite clear what you're trying to accomplish - you're already filtering by the search text and job role and label in your `filterAll` computed property - what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I haven't made myself that clear, what I am trying to accomplish is to create the two select options using the data from the api, I am able to display the data in the select but its also displaying duplicates, I want the select options to display unique values and have them values filter the data displayed in the table.

I created a function called JobRoleList that accomplishes what I want and only displays unique values for position.  My problem is, is that I can't get it to filter the filterAll data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. You're binding the wrong value to the job role select. Right now your code says `:value="item.Position"` when the `JobRoleList` variable is an array of strings. So when you click select there won't be a value for `JobRole`

```
        <select v-model="JobRole">
            <option value="">Select a Position</option>
            <option v-for="item in JobRoleList" :value="item.Position">{{item}}</option>
        </select>
```

2. You're filtering the wrong variable in your `filterAll` computed variable in the `jobRole` part

```
    if (vm.JobRole) {
        vm.JobRole = filtered.filter(function(item){
            return item.Position.match(vm.JobRole)
            console.log(JobRole);
        });
        // This should say "filtered =" not "vm.JobRole ="
    }
```

There's also a much more succinct way to get a unique list of values using ES6:

```
    JobRoleList: function({ users }) {
      return [...new Set(users.map(d => d.Position))];
    }
```

You can also make your search all lower case letters before matching to improve the user experience.

```
        filtered = users.filter(function(item){
          return item.People.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1
        });
```

I've made a codepen with a working demo: https://codepen.io/CodingDeer/pen/abomBXP

Comment: Hi Cathy, thank you very much for this, its been a real help and I really appreciate it.